# My script takes too long to run

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, event-log, powershell-3.0

My script reports on event errors from the application, system and security logs within 24 hours. The script takes an average of 8 mins to run. I believe these particular statements contribute to the problem:

```
$Lap = Get-EventLog -computername $server -LogName $logname -after (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)
$Lap | where {$_.entryType -match "Error"} | Sort-Object eventid |
  group-object eventid | Format-Table Name, Count -auto | fl |
  out-string | Add-Content $eventlogfile
```

If I replace the `-after` parameter with `-newest`, the script runs quickly. Any thoughts of why the above statement contributes to the script taking awhile to run?

*Edit*
Doing some research, I learned that by using the get-eventlog cmdlet PS parses the entire event log.

*Measure how long it'll take to determine the amount of application errors found within the last 24 hours*
`Measure-Command -Expression {get-eventlog -ComputerName server123 -LogName Application -EntryType Error -after (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)}`


**Total time: 54 secs**


Count how many application errors popped up in the last 24 hours* 


`$logs1 = get-eventlog -ComputerName server123 -LogName Application -EntryType Error -after (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)
 $logs1.count`


**There are 3 errors**


`measure-command -expression {get-eventlog -ComputerName server123 -logname application -Newest 3 }`


**43 milliseconds**

Any thoughts of why specifying the `-after` parameter with the `get-eventlog` cmdlet returns results much longer than specifing the `-newest` parameter?

Comment: Because you have too many events in your event log in the last 24 hours?

Comment: There are less than 20,13,7 events in my application, system and security log respectively.

Comment: The some 20 event log entries are what you get *after* filtering, no?

Comment: Did you try to reduce your test case? For example, does this line take as long? `$Lap = Get-EventLog -computername $server -LogName $logname -after (Get-Date).AddHours(-24) $Lap| where {$_.entryType -match "Error"}` (I removed sort-object and the rest) Try to reduce it as much as possible, so it's easier to pinpoint the issue (if any).

Comment: @vonPryz Yes those numbers are the result of 'after' filtering

Comment: @Neolisk I didn't reduce the statements. But I will update you when I do so.

Comment: What's the relevance of the disk space discussion here? If checking disk space isn't contributing significantly to the execution time, edit that out, as it's only distracting from your primary question.

Comment: @vonPryz Yes, there are 20 event log entries or so _after_ filtering

Answer (score 3):

You transfer all events of the past 24 hours over the network and then filter them on the local computer:

```psh
$Lap = Get-EventLog -computername $server -LogName $logname -after (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)
$Lap | where {$_.entryType -match "Error"} | Sort-Object eventid | ...
```

Doing the filtering directly with `Get-EventLog` should speed things up, because that way only the error events of the past 24 hours are transferred over the network:

```psh
$Lap = Get-EventLog -Computer $server -LogName $logname -EntryType 'Error' -After (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)
$Lap | Sort-Object eventid | ...
```

Comment: This!  Always filter in the cmdlet if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

The cmdlet `Measure-Command` can be used to find out how long a command will take. Use it to find out what is going on. Split up the script a bit to find the most expensive operation. Something like so,

```
Measure-Command -Expression { $Lap = Get-EventLog -computername $server -LogName $logname -after (Get-Date).AddHours(-24) }
Measure-Command -Expression { $lap2 = $Lap| ? {$_.entryType -match "Error"}}
Measure-Command -Expression { $Lap3 = $Lap2 |Sort-Object eventid
# Keep splitting / unsplitting statements until you find the costly one
Measure-Command -Expression { $Lap3 |group-object eventid|Format-Table Name, Count -auto|fl|out-string|Add-Content $eventlogfile }
```

Comment: It takes roughly 7 minutes to execute both commands. `Measure-Command -Expression { $Lap = Get-EventLog -computername $server -LogName $logname -after (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)} `.  **~~~~~~~~~~~~~**    `$Lap = Get-EventLog -computername $server -LogName $logname -EntryType 'Error' -after (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)}`

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before, and using -After with large log files is definitely a performance problem.

I've used the index numbers to speed it up when doing repetitive log reads:

```
$last_index = get-content index_history.txt

#Get the index number of the last log entry 
$index = (Get-EventLog -ComputerName $_ -LogName $log -newest 1).index 

#calculate number of events to retrieve 
if ($last_index){$n = $index - $last_index} 

#get the log entries  
$Lap = Get-EventLog -computername $server -LogName $logname -Newest $n

$index | set-content index_history.txt
```